# Converting MP3 to WAV on Android and controlling the Quality/bitrate

Tags: android, mp3, wav

I am using [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) to convert MP3 to WAV however I need to lower the quality/ bitrate as it is taking 1-2 minutes to convert on a Nexus 7.  The wav does not need to be high quality as its background music for a SIP call.

Does anyone know if you can control the quality/bitrate of this library or know of any other Android compatible library that can do the job?

Comment: mp3 has a bitrate, WAV has not. The bitrate depends on the mp3-file and may vary during a song. So you can't just decrease the bitrate in a wav file as well as you can't decrease the bitrate in the mp3 itself without decoding it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so how would you convert a MP3 to a wav and lower the quality of it, size?  limit it to mono?

Comment: Although mp3 and wav support different sampling rates, they often tend to use 44.1 kHz (because of the quality). However, you can try to use a lower sampling rate, like 22.05 kHz. This leads, of course, to lower quality since the higher frequencies are cut off. But I don't think that this increases the performance of the decompression. Do you know http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Docs/riffmci.pdf (page 56)?